# How to query with filters for every element in an array?

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am experimenting with GraphQL, AppSync and AWS Amplify for a new project. Let's say I have the following schema:

```
type Test @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  text_pieces: [String]
}
```

Now, I have created this through Amplify and it automatically generates queries like `ListTests` which accepts filtering. Filtering accepts lots of useful operators such as `beginsWith` or `contains`. Let's say I have these objects as data source:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "FirstTest",
    "text_pieces": [
      "FirstPiece",
      "SecondPiece"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "SecondTest",
    "text_pieces": [
      "ThirdPiece",
      "FourthPiece"
    ]
  }
]
```

So I can build a query like:

```
query FirstTests {
  listTests(filter: {name: {beginsWith: "First"}}) {
    items {
      name
      text_pieces
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns, as expected:

```
  {
    "name": "FirstTest",
    "text_pieces": [
      "FirstPiece",
      "SecondPiece"
    ]
  }
```

and I can also make a query like

```
query FirstPieces {
  listTests(filter: {text_pieces: {contains: "FirstPiece"}}) {
    items {
      name
      text_pieces
    }
  }
}
```

which again returns:

```
  {
    "name": "FirstTest",
    "text_pieces": [
      "FirstPiece",
      "SecondPiece"
    ]
  }
```

However, I'd also like to be able to use an operator like `beginsWith` **with every element in the text_pieces array** and filter through that. So something like

```
query FirstPieces {
  listTests(filter: {text_pieces: {items { beginsWith: "First"}}}) {
    items {
      name
      text_pieces
    }
  }
}
```

which would still return

```
  {
    "name": "FirstTest",
    "text_pieces": [
      "FirstPiece",
      "SecondPiece"
    ]
  }
```

Is that supported by Amplify by concatenating the already available filters? Or probably something that would need its own resolver?

Comment: Maybe what you need is that, it's just a guess, never tried before
`
query FirstPieces {
  listTests() {
    items (filter: {name: {beginsWith: "First"}}) {
      name
      text_pieces
    }
  }
}